# Order Players on the SUM of their association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, group-by, associations, sum, has-many

I have a database with 6500 `players` and each player has an average of 15 game `results`.

**Use case**

I want to generate a list of players, ordered by the **sum** of their **prize** money (a field in the results table).
I prefer this to be in some sort of scope, so I can also filter the list on the player's country, etc.

**Performance**

I have seen posts that mention a `cache_counter` field for performance. In my case **I have thousands of result records (75.000+)** so I don't want the calculations being done every time someone visits the generated listings.

**Question**

What is the best pattern to solve this? And how do I implement it?

**Models**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

**Schemas**

```
  create_table "players", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "nationality"
  end

  create_table "results", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "player_id"
    t.date     "event_date"
    t.integer  "place"
    t.integer  "prize"
  end
```

**Update**

What I am trying to accomplish is getting to a point where I can use:

```
@players = Player.order_by_prize
```

and

```
@players = Player.filter_by_country('USA').order_by_prize('desc')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
class Player
 scope :order_by_prize, joins(:results).select('name, sum(results.prize) as total_prize').order('total_prize desc')
```

Refer rails api - [active record querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for details.

Comment: I had to make some adjustments to your suggestion, and now it accurately orders them by sum of their prizes: `scope :order_by_prize, joins(:results).select('players.id, players.name, sum(results.prize) as total_prize').group('players.id').order('total_prize desc')`. However, the results only show `player.id` and `player.name`, not the `total_prize` result?

Comment: Btw, I made those adjustments because I am using PostgreSQL and in the console it told me to include a group by clause after running your code.

Comment: Nevermind! In the console the `total_prize` doesn't show on screen in the resulting output, but the attribute is correctly set and available. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am surprised that it needs "group('players.id') clause. Need to find out more about why it does so. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: The group('players.id') clause creates individual sums for all of the players. Without it, all of the prizes for all of the players are added together.