# How do I sort records based on sum of a particular attribute in a set of associations in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

guys! I would like to sort comments based on the total ratings score where the total rating score is the sum of the ratings' score attributes for each comment.

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :comment, :class_name => 'Comment', :foreign_key => 'comment_id'

end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ratings
end

Rating schema
  create_table "ratings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "comment_id"
    t.integer  "score"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what RDBMS you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to order by the sum of associated records columns like this

```
Comment.joins(:ratings).group('comments.id').order('sum(ratings.score) desc')
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer for doing the count through a select call.
[Order Players on the SUM of their association model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526012/order-players-on-the-sum-of-their-association-model). This would be the suggested way.

Another way would be to include a method to sum all the rating's scores in your comment model.

```
def rating_score_sum
  ratings.sum(:score)
end
```

Then, you can sort your collection using that method.

```
Comment.all.sort_by(&:rating_score_sum)
```

Though this will calculate the score sum of all ratings for each comment every time and may become an issue as your database grows. I would consider saving that sum on the comments table and updating it on every new  rating.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this easily with:

```
Comment.joins(:ratings).select('comments.*, SUM(ratings.score) as rating_score').order('rating_score DESC')
```

You could also try using `includes` instead of `joins` or even `eager_load` as it will preload the association (ratings) and improve the performance of this query.

Comment: Not if you're using Postgres. You would need a group clause.

Comment: Sure thing. My answer is based on: what RDBMS you are using ? – Arup Rakshit, MySQL, thank you. - nebulus